# Function mb_strlen Fail

Tags: plugins

While trying to create a package using "Duplicator" plugin, I'm getting the error:

`Function mb_strlen Fail`

Am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: I tried googling for this issue. however not getting any hints for Function mb_strlen fail. There are multiple posts in forums for Zip Archive. Kindly consider my issue. Am quite new to Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have to install and activate the PHP module [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) in order to get the **required** [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function on your system.